# I want the Copy Rotation constraint to only return the offset of the target, not its actual value

Tags: animation, constraints

[image]

Both the owner and the target are rotated away from the world axes so I have to set the owner to local space for it to rotate correctly. I think this may be part of the problem. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no Copy Rotation with offset option.
Try the following:

1. Add an **Empty** object at the location of **wishbones.001** and add that **"Copy Rotation"** constraint to the **Empty** object.
2. Once done - add **"Child Of"** constraint to **wishbones.001** with Target - the **Empty** object.

Comment: I am testing this now, seems to work. Setting the 'set inverse' option on the 'child of' contraint is necessary. Will give you your tick once i'm 100%.